# ASP.Net Responsive Web Design or Native Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, .net, web-services

I am working on a project requirement.the project will be a ASP.Net Web application.
Database will be Microsoft SQL Server.this ASP.Net Web application will contain all the business logic and functionalities.

I have another requirement that all the functionalities in that web application should be accessible through mobile(IOS/Android) devices.

I hope we can do this in 2 ways.

1.Develop that web application with Responsive UI Design that supports all IOS/Android mobile devices.

2.Develop the web application business logic functionalities as .Net WebServices.Then Develop Separate Android/IOS applications to communicate with .Net Web Services and provide Better user interaction in Mobile.

Which way is the best way? Is there any other ways to accomplish this task?

among above two ways,How hard to make it possible / which is the hardest way?

Please somebody give a good solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how "native" the app should be. Is it ok for the client to open a browser to visit the app? Or maybe it's enough to use phone gap to "emulate" a native app. From the actual point of view it`s hard to say what solution would fullfill the requirements. However, developing a native app arises a new maintenance channel. If you develop a reponsive web app it will be the only app that needs to be maintained. With every additional app you create (android, IOS and maybe Windows) you will create an additional app that needs to be maintained and to be tested, rolled out etc. Just keep that in mind while designing the architecture.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I hope, Responsive Web App will be suitable for my case.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you should go with responsive web application.**

Because as your are developing a new application then if you go with responsive then will save you time and the **version problems which users face with **Android/IOS**** will not occur with you.
Although you can provide full functionality to user with responsive. If you develop mobile application then it has some limits.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Its true that Responsive Web App will save the time and Version Problems.